# fabric8-maven-plugin - Generator for Dropwizard app (java-exec?)

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard, fabric8-maven-plugin

I'm new to fabric8-maven-plugin.

I have a Dropwizard fat jar which I'd like to containerize for OpenShift/okd. It seems the recommended way would invoke the java-exec generator: http://maven.fabric8.io/#generator-java-exec

Problem is that Dropwizard apps have a config file argument that must be provided, but I'm not sure how to instruct the generator to do so.

Correct invocation should be:

`java -jar hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml`

The generator does the following, which is missing arguments:

`java -jar hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be the simplest approach:

*Use the `exec-maven-plugin` in your build configuration. Supply the needed arguments: one for the command and another for the configuration file location.*

The following example is a random search result: https://github.com/christian-posta/microservices-by-example-source/blob/master/hola-dropwizard/pom.xml#L103-L114.

It seems to implement the approach described here: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/microservices-for-java-developers/page/3/dropwizard-for-microservices#chapter-3-dropwizard-for-microservices